# go to definition in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio

what do I have to do to jump to the right class not the metadata?

in visual studio 2010 while working on c# code I right click on some code to jump to "Go To Definition"
sometimes shows the right class where my object is define and sometimes show me the Metadata not the right class...

why is this ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It only shows you the source code of a class if that class is available in your solution. If you're referencing a project whose source you have, you can add it to the solution as a project reference, and "Go To Definition" should behave as you'd expect. If you're referencing a compiled DLL, "Go To Definition" will only display metadata.

Comment: +1. I like to add an out of topic trick: To to see the source code of external references, install .NET Reflector plugin. (http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

Comment: I get the same behavior when the DLL project is in the solution. The code is right there, but I get metadata.

Comment: Maybe you added the reference to the DLL file instead of adding it to the project.

Comment: Thanks djacobson... I do have the source in another project and i did have add the dll to the References. (I only see available dlls to select when I try to add the other project to References).

Comment: Gerardo...Can you detail a bit more your reply...Maybe you added the reference to the DLL file instead of adding it to the project<<

Answer (score 3):

if you added references to other project than F12 will go to the actual source code but for the DLL it will go to the meta data if defind

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio will go to the metadata when the reference is a DLL or an EXE - it doesn't "know" about the source code.

It will go to the source code when you have references a *project*.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, Visual Studio cannot show you the actual source code for an assembly that you only have in compiled form (i.e. .exe or .dll). If you really need to see how something was implemented, then you can use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to decompile it for you, though the resulting code will probably be less intelligible than the original (no comments, variable names will be lost, etc.).